# Android phone is not detected in visual studio 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am developing Xamarin forms app. I am not able to deploy app in nexus 6p( phone is not listed in device list ). Tried below steps, still phone is not detected.

- I have installed Google USB Driver using Android SDK manager.  [image]
- I have downloaded usb driver for nexus 6p and done 'Update driver software'
  option in device manager under 'Portable devices' section. Device
  gets displayed as 'Nexus 6p' within Portable devices section in
  device manager and also seen as local drive( next to C: drive ).  [image][image]
- Selected droid project as startup project.

But phone is not listed in visual studio device list. Any help?

Comment: your adb interface shows an exclamation mark.. also did you set the phone to usb debugging?

Comment: What _does_ the list show? And did you enable developer mode on your phone? For this go into your phone's about screen and tap the build number field a whole bunch of times until you get an alert.

Comment: i enabled usb debugging in phone...phone is currently in developer mode

Comment: current list of devices consists of emulators only

Comment: @SurajRao where i can confirm this? "your adb interface shows an exclamation mark"

Comment: your pic of device manager.. above the Nexus 6

Comment: You may need to install the driver: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate SDK with the SDK manager (I think it is called)?

Comment: @SurajRao yes it shows exclamation mark...i think it is related to our problem...if it is so..then how can we avoid that exclamation mark?

Comment: Do you have the adb where you have installed the SDK?

Comment: @OwenRansen i have installed android sdk tools 25.2.4 and Android sdk platform tools 25.0.3

Comment: run `adb list devices`

Comment: @SurajRao while running adb device command...no device is listed in result

Comment: so adb installation is fine.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list

Comment: @BytesGuy downloaded the driver and tried to 'Update driver software' in portable device section.. it shows a dilaog stating "windows has determined that the driver is up to date"

Comment: @SurajRao tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170392/android-device-does-not-show-up-in-adb-list Delete the device from Device Manager.
Rescan for hardware changes.

Comment: @pg90 I would ensure Developer Mode is enabled on the device.  If it is then go into the Developer options and Revoke USB Debugging Authorizations.  Disconnect the phone and reconnect and hope it asks for authorisation again.

Comment: but rescan option does not shows mobile as "Unknown driver"...it results as mobile already having driver

Comment: @AlanClark i diconnected the phone..then revoked USB Debugging Authorizations. Connected again, but it did not asked for authorization

Comment: @pg90 [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224370/visual-studio-and-android-device-monitor-doesnt-detect-any-devices):  *You most likely did not grant access to the device. Try to go into the developer settings on the smartphone and revoke the USB debugging authorisation. Then connect the phone to the pc and and wait for a popup on the phone which you should accept. After accepting you should see your device with adb devices.*

Comment: @pg90 I suspect that the driver you have installed is the standard manufacturer's driver and not one that enables debugging.  I would suggest uninstalling the device from Device Manager and then installing the device again but using the Google USB Driver as you tried before.  Uninstalling the device should ensure no existing driver is causing an issue with this.

Comment: @AlanClark I tried it, but after uninstalling the driver the mobile name gets removed from Portable devices section. So i have to disconnect the usb cable and connect again. While reconnecting, the mobile under Portable devices is having driver again

Comment: I solved a maybe similar problem using the Lenovo ADB driver for a Google Nexus 6: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84871/is-the-adb-driver-installer-safe

Answer (score 8):

[image: Make sure the 'USB DEBUGGING' option in DEVELOPER OPTIONS remains checked on your connected Android Device.]

**Make sure the 'USB DEBUGGING' option in DEVELOPER OPTIONS remains checked on your connected Android Device.**

I've lost lots of time because this item would uncheck itself for some reason between reboots/restarts and Enabling/Disabling the DEVELOPER OPTIONS.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone else is still struggling with this in 2017, and your USB debugging is definitely on and it's still not appearing - I managed to fix this by turning developer options `OFF` then `ON` again from the device's settings. Also ensure that the **USB option** is set to:

> Charging - Just charge this phone

I couldn't get any other method other than this to work. The device was then immediately detected by Visual Studio 2017 for me.

Answer (score 2):

You ABD interface is not installed on your system, so first install the ABD driver from your local machine using (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver).  
And check your device is in developer mode. 
If all the setting will be good then your visual studio automatically detect your device and you can start to debug your app on your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed VS2017 in parallel to VS2015, you also may have a look here [Android devices not showed anymore in VS2015 after installing VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224370/visual-studio-and-android-device-monitor-doesnt-detect-any-devices#51594570)