# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't see Android device

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, samsung-mobile, unreal-engine4

I am trying to develop an app using a game engine, that I build with VS2017.  My phone is not recognized in either VS or the game engine, however it is recognized in Android Studio and I have been able to deploy an app to it.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38224370/visual-studio-and-android-device-monitor-doesnt-detect-any-devices) but all of these suggestions I had already done, as evidenced by the phone being recognized in Android Studio.  One thing that may reinforce some sort of VS/Windows/Lineage issue is that after revoking ADB debugging authorization, unplugging and plugging the phone back in, I could never get the authorization dialog to come back to reauthorize the connection.  Until, that is, I tried to deploy a test app in Android studio, and then it came back and I could authorize the connection.  So, even though the device wasn't authorized it was recognized in AS, while even when it was authorized it was not recognized in VS.

The phone's OS is Lineage 16.

All other windows functions, file transfer, picture transfer, etc, work correctly.

The Samsung drivers are also installed and not just Win10.

I've set root access on the phone to both apps and adb and adb only, with no difference in behavior.

I've tried multiple cables, as well as USB2.0 and 3.0 connections on my pc.  About the only thing I haven't tried is rebooting my pc, but since I already started this message I'll do that after I post.

Here's hoping someone might have an idea!!

Comment: This question seems to me more about configuring VS and your phone. This is not the place to ask questions like that. assuming that it is about code, you are expected to post a minimal reproducible example. please provide the example or close the question.

Comment: Thanks for reading my post again and noticing that I linked a discussion on this forum that speaks to the exact same problem.